# Match reserved single character escape sequences and print them literally

Tags: javascript, regex

**JSON:** `{"name":"firstName\nSecondName"}`

I am trying to format this JSON, to print:

```
{
  "name": "firstName\nSecondName"
}
```

---

**Attempt 1:**

```
token.replace(/\n|\b|\f|\r|\t|\v|\0|\\/, "\\$&")
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
token.replace(/\\[bfnrtv0'"\\]/, "\\$&") /* This regexp doesn't work at all */
```

*(all formatting implementation code not shown here)*

When it comes to printing literal `\n`, my code `process.write.stdout(token)` prints a new line instead:

```
{
  "name": "firstName
  SecondName"
}
```

*How can I print reserved escape sequence literally in JS?*

Comment: did you try JSON.stringify method???

Comment: I want to do it without using JSON.stringify. How JSON.stringify does it?